# MySQL optimize a query COUNT-ing DISTINCT values or NULL IF NO ROWS

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need to get **the count of distinct athletes** from a **times table** where **time is less than some-other-time**. But the tricky part is that **if there are no times at all** (to compare against, **I need to get NULL in return**).

Let me give you an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO teams 
VALUES (NULL, 'Texas'), (NULL,'Oklahoma');

mysql> select * from teams;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Texas    |
|  2 | Oklahoma |
+----+----------+


CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `athlete` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `team_id` (`team_id`)
);

INSERT INTO times VALUES 
  (NULL, 1, 19.10, 'Dave'),
  (NULL, 1, 19.09, 'Dave'),
  (NULL, 1, 19.07, 'Dave'),
  (NULL, 1, 19.56, 'John'),
  (NULL, 1, 19.60, 'John'),
  (NULL, 1, 19.75, 'John');

mysql> select * from times;
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| id | team_id | time  | athlete |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | 19.10 | Dave    |
|  2 |       1 | 19.09 | Dave    |
|  3 |       1 | 19.07 | Dave    |
|  4 |       1 | 19.56 | John    |
|  5 |       1 | 19.60 | John    |
|  6 |       1 | 19.75 | John    |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
```

So far we have two teams. `Team 1` has **two athletes** with **6 times** and `Team 2` has no athletes (and times respectively).

If I want to know `How many Athletes from Texas are faster than 19.50` I can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) FROM times WHERE time < 19.50 and team_id = 1;
+-------------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
```

which is correct.

And if I want to check `How many Athletes from Texas are faster than 19.00`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) FROM times WHERE time < 19.00 and team_id = 1;
+-------------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
```

is also correct (because we have **two athletes** from `Texas`).

But if I want to check: `How many Athletes from Oklahoma are faster than 19.00`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) FROM times WHERE time < 19.00 and team_id = 2;
+-------------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT athlete) |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
```

is **not correct** because we have **no times** from `Oklahoma`. So here I need to get `NULL` in return.

I managed to find a solution with a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  IF(
    EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM times WHERE team_id = 2
    ),
    COUNT(DISTINCT athlete),
    NULL
  ) as count
FROM `times`
WHERE
  team_id = 2 AND time < 19.00;
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|  NULL |
+-------+
```

which is correct and if I test it for `Texas`, I get:

```
SELECT 
  IF(
    EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM times WHERE team_id = 1
    ),
    COUNT(DISTINCT athlete),
    NULL
  ) as count
FROM `times`
WHERE
  team_id = 1 AND time < 19.00;

+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

It returns the correct answer.

But the problem is that I used a `sub-query` which **have to mimic** all the filters of the main query except for the `time < 19.00`. In my real application there are a lot more filters and I'm searching for a solution without a sub-query.

One thing that came to mind was to use SUM(CASE)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
  WHEN time < 19.50 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END) as count
FROM `times`
WHERE team_id = 2;

+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|  NULL |
+-------+
```

The problem is that this is **counting-times not distinct athletes**, thus for `Texas` I will get the wrong count;

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
  WHEN time < 19.50 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END) as count
FROM `times`
WHERE team_id = 1;

+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     3 |
+-------+
```

I get **3 times** faster that `19.50` instead of **1 athlete** faster than `19.50`.

Comment: '19.50' is a string. 19.50 is a number

Comment: `MySQL` is properly casting '19.50' to number. However fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
SELECT a.name
     , MAX(b.athlete < 19.50) faster 
  FROM teams a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN times b 
    ON b.team_id = a.id 
 GROUP BY a.name;
```

Comment: Nice trick, but if I change `19.50` with `20.00` I need to get `2` as a count, because there are two athletes faster than `20.00`.

Comment: I think I found a solution I'll post it in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found a solution that again has a sub-query, but at least I wont need to repeat all the filters twice (which can satisfy me for now if there isn't any better). Here is it:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.time < 19.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count
FROM (
  SELECT athlete, min(time) as time 
  FROM times 
  WHERE team_id = 2 group by athlete
) a;
```

This way I get `NULL` for **Team 2** and `0` for **Team 1**